# Keep objects inside view when window resized in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently developing universal windows app as school work and I have big problem with keeping things visible to the user no matter the windows or screen size. 


I made menu and frame, and they seem to resize correctly, frame keeps same distance from window border no matter the size ( as long as its empty), but the frame content just disappear when window height or width is changed, as shown below:
[image: Frame content when window is full screen]
[image: Frame content when window size is chnaged]
(grey area is the frame)

All I wish is that for example, one text box would have 25% of the frame width, some other block next 25% and so on...
I checked few solutions from MSDN and stackoverflow, but non seem to work so far.


Thanks for your help & time in advance

XAML code of my project in current state:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Fublisher.real_program"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Fublisher"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="480" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Grid x:Name="GR_STRAN" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid x:Name="GR_MENU" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition">
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU" Content="&#xEA37;" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" Click="CL_MENU"/>
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU_DOMOV" Content="&#xE80F;" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" Margin="0,65,0,0" FontSize="20" Click="CL_DOMOV"/>
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU_VSEBINA" Content="&#xE70F;" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,130,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="20" Click="CL_VSEBINA"/>
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU_ABOUT" Content="&#xE946;" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="20"/>
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU_USER" Content="&#xE2AF;" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,65" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="20"/>
                <Button x:Name="BT_MENU_OBLIKA" Content="&#xE771;" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="59.8" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,195,0,0" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition" FontSize="20"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="GR_VSEBINA" Margin="60,0,0,0" Background="#FFF1F1F1">
                <Frame x:Name="frame6" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition" Margin="10" Background="#FFE2E2E2"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And code of page showed in frame:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Fublisher.home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Fublisher"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1860" Height="1080">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1080"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1860"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="480" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="336" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="601">
            <Grid Height="336" Width="601">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hey!" FontSize="120" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Margin="23,0" Height="143" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
                <Button x:Name="button" Content="&#xEE56;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="53.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,66" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{x:Null}" Height="99" Width="187"/>
                <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="&#xE771;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="53.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="207,0,207,66" Background="{x:Null}" Height="99" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
                <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="&#xE78B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="53.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,1,64" Background="{x:Null}" Height="101" Width="187"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Write" FontSize="26.667" TextAlignment="Center" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="187"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy" Margin="207,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Design" FontSize="26.667" TextAlignment="Center" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Publish" FontSize="26.667" TextAlignment="Center" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="187"/>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Without seeing your XAML, it's impossible to say what's going on. Can you post it?

Comment: I already made some changes to the UI, will post it in a sec

Comment: Right, so you see all your hard set heights/widths/margins? That's your culprit.... Your layout will never be fluid doing that. For example your `Grid` with the fixed Height/Width sitting inside a redundant ViewBox and filled with objects using fixed margins as if they're on a fixed canvas is a perfect example of how not to make a good layout. Since you don't have a lot going on in there, if you give a visual example of how you want that stuff to consistently lay out then I'll give you an example of how to do it correctly to achieve your desired result. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardcoded widths and heights will be difficult, and probably, impossible to make work in a truly UWP App. This is why Microsoft has [Design adaptive UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide#design-adaptive-ui-with-adaptive-panels) with adaptive panels. Much like HTML pages, objects should flow relative to each other. See the RelativePanel in the link, and then you can add code like

```
RelativePanel.RightOf="textBox1"
```

to indicate a button is to be to the RightOf textBox1, as in their example.